# advagg drupal module breaking my js file

Tags: 7, css-js-aggregation

I am using [advagg module](https://www.drupal.org/project/advagg) to improve my website performance and I also using [date picker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) jquery UI function for date functionality.

I have datePicker  intialization `$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();` . It works perfectly, I can Even see the `calender` but when I am selecting the date, I don't see any alert.

for Some reason On `datepicker` function `onSelect` is not working when I have `advagg` enabled.

```
 jQuery('#datepicker').datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        alert(dateText);
        glImgExpiry = dateText;
      }
});
```

If I disabled `advagg`, It works without any problem and I can see `alert(dateText)`.
This is happening when I am configuraing `advagg` to my `dev/test` , In my local I am not able to configure correctly because I only see `per file setting` for `jscompression and other settings` in my `dev/test`.So sadly, I am not able to reproduce same issue in my local and it is breaking in my `test/dev` environment.

I know the information, I am giving is not sufficient to get the issue/ problem I am describing. I am just hoping some one might have faced same kind of issue and can help me resolve this problem.

### **EDIT**

As suggested I have tried putting the `datepicker` onSelect function inside `drupal.behavior`

```
(function($) {
    //add drupal 7 code
    Drupal.behaviors.myfunction = {
        attach: function(context, settings) {
//end drupal calls

            jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                jQuery('#gl_img_datepicker').datepicker({
                    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
                        alert(dateText);
                     }
                });
//some jquery goodness here...
            });

        }};
})
        (jQuery);
```

But I still dont see the `alert(dateText);` in the page.

Thanks your help is really appreciated.

Comment: how are you adding you js? Is your js contained within a drupal.behavior?

Comment: using `drupal_add_js($path_to_module . '/js/myjsFile.js');`

Comment: in what function are you calling drupal_add_js? Is your js in a drupal.behavior? Are there any js errors reported on the page?

Comment: I have custom module and in hook function and in `mymodule.inc` file I am including the drupal_add_js($path_to_module . '/js/myjsFile.js'); at the top for that file

Comment: Please answer the questions.  
in what function are you calling drupal_add_js (what hook)? Is your js in a drupal.behavior? Are there any js errors reported on the page?

Comment: I dont see any error in my console, And I am not using `drupal behavior` as described here - https://www.drupal.org/node/756722#behaviors . I am just using `drupal_add_js($path_to_module . '/js/myjsFile.js');` in my ``.inc` file.

Comment: I have not used drupal behavior, But other functions like `onClick event` and `onChange event`  works correctly but jquery ui datepicker `onSelect` is not working

Comment: If you are not using behaviors, you may expect your code to conflict with other Drupal modules. Wrap it with behavior and see again.

Comment: hmmm .. ok I will check with that But then how other jQuery events are working

Comment: @Mołot : it is not working even when I wrap it with behavior

Comment: Thanks every one :) , it seems that problem is not with `drupal.behavior` or `advagg module` but with `datepicker function` ... found answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/1274403/1877909

Comment: But I would explore more on `drupal.behavior` and write my `JS` in that format so that I could avoid conflict with other drupal modules. Thanks alot for information @Mołot

Comment: If some one would add the answer along with drupal.behavior explanation, I would love to accept that ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to add document.ready to a behavior.
Read about drupal behaviors [HERE](https://www.drupal.org/node/756722#behaviors) or at a good blog post [HERE](http://www.amazeelabs.com/en/blog/drupal-behaviors-quick-how).
Basically I think Drupal adds a document.ready which calls all the behaviors. The behaviors are also called after an ajax call is returned (sending the new content returned by the ajax to the behaviors via the context variable). Which is why we use the context variable in the jquery selector.
Your javascript should probably look like this.

```
(function ($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.myfunction = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      $('#gl_img_datepicker', context).datepicker({
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
          alert(dateText);
        }
      });
    }
  };
})(jQuery);
```